# React JS best way to manage session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I am creating web-app with react. It is my first JS project so I decided to ask for advice.

I do not know how to manage user session. 
I am using axios.post to connect with server but I do not know how should my app behave after successful authorize. Now app just changes page to for example /myaccount.

Please tell me what should I use ensure that user cannot access /myaccount without login.

Comment: I think that this is way too broad. It depends completely on your backend and architecture and it is also opinion based. Maybe you have a stateless REST API in your backend and should use tokens to keep track of the "user session", but there are many possible ways of doing this.

Comment: The most important for me is to keep my code as simple as it possible and provide safety. So I have got tokens which are stored in sessionStorage, but it is the problem because session storage is connected with only one card, so user cannot open new card and go to myApp/myaccount without login.